# Which units can dance?

Tags: starcraft-2

`/dance` can get Zealots to go at it with their glow sticks, but what other units can dance in *Starcraft II*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's your list :)

- Terran:

  - **Marines**,
  - **Marauders**, and
  - **Thors**.
- Protoss:

  - **Zealots** and
  - **High Templar**.
- Zerg:

  - **Zerglings**,
  - **Hydralisks**, and
  - **Ultralisks**.

Comment: Do you know if this is the same set of units that can `/cheer`?

Comment: +1 from me if you link videos or show some screenshots

Comment: Ask and you shall receive: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsCij0_vVrY

Comment: @NickT Yes, the same set of units also cheer.

Comment: @Sorean for future reference if you dump a YouTube link in your post it will link the video (you can even link to a particular time in it with `#t=XmYYs`).

Comment: Overlords can also do /dance.